# Nginx 'allow' returning 404

Tags: nginx

Judging by my access logs, I have a site that hits "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" whenever a user loads the admin page of a site. I wanted to whitelist some IPs to access this page, so I added the following rule:

```
location /admin/ {
    allow $whitelistIP;
    deny all;
}
```

This seems to properly return a 403 when accesses from a third party, but when accessed by the privileged party, a 404 page is returned. If I disable this stanza completely, then access is returned and all parties can load the admin site again. As such, I am wondering why a 404 is being returned for the privileged party when all the stanza does is allow an IP...

Comment: You need to post the complete `server` block.

Comment: `allow` doesn't return anything. It just allows you to get inside the location, but occasionally  there is nothing to show, so nginx return 404.

Provide additional information if you want more accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This answer is most likely wrong.

If your `/admin/` is normally provided with PHP via FastCGI, then the problem is that the location block you showed above overrides the default location block for PHP scripts.

In nginx, location blocks are not chained, the most precise location block is used for a request. Locations with regular expressions (like the `location ~ \.php$`) have less preference than more conrete location blocks like you specify above.

Another problem point might be that this location block overrides a general URL rewrite block.

Comment: You are wrong about precedence. Regexp locations are preferred over normal prefix ones. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

Comment: According to my experience and the example in nginx documentation you referred, regexes are used if directory matching fails. The example in nginx documentation does exactly what I describe above.

Comment: the location with the longest matching prefix is selected and remembered. ... **If no match** with a regular expression is found then the configuration of the prefix location remembered earlier is used.

Comment: Ah true, I was looking at the example with configuration D and E, when actually configuration C and E would apply to this question.